How do you detect and replace '0a' in Fortran
Looking at sample data of a user supplied field '0a' is embedded in the middle of the field:
54 52 41 4e 53 46 45 41 0a 22 2c 75 6e 61 70 70
The ascii text originates from a user data entry tool that allows the users to enter multi-line data and substitutes their carriage return with '0a'.  My goal is to substitute the '0a's with a space, while leaving the CRLF (0d 0a) strings intact. (Thus retaining an ascii Windows file in all other respects.)
But for the life of me, I can't figure out how to detect a '0a' in Fortran properly. I'm opening the file as an unformatted stream and walking the stream byte by byte until I get to one that isn't preceded by an '0d' but can't get my logic to pick it up for the substitution. How do you tell Fortran to detect characters like '0a' and '0d'? I'm compiling with gfortran.

Open the file for stream access. Read one character at a time.  Compare the read character to 0a.

I have tried. It's not working. I'm reading each char into a character*1 variable, but I don't know how to specify what to test against. if(byte.eq.'0a')? I don't think that's right, but you get the idea. If I had an example of the if statement....

Does the following help?  I used a string instead of reading from a stream.  Same method should work.
program foo

   implicit none

   integer i
   character(len=10) str

   str = '0123456789'
   str(5:5) = achar(10)
   print *, str

   do i = 1, len_trim(str)
      if (ichar(str(i:i)) == 10) print *, i
   end do
   
end program foo

You can also use index(str, achar(10))

For some reason, the write is not writing the altered byte to the stream regardless of action="readwrite", that's the problem. I have to figure out why, since I created the file I'm trying to change. Thanks for the logic assist.

@kris44dad At some point you have to post a minimal reproducible example of your code, so we can comment on its correctness, and possibly compile and test it. Without seeing any code it's difficult to help you further.

Ya, I know. I'll do better.

So, you're trying to replace the character in the file on-the-fly?
program foo

   implicit none

   integer fd, i
   character(len=10) str
   character c

   str = '0123456789'
   str(5:5) = achar(10)  ! Put 0x0a into string

   ! Create file
   open(newunit=fd,file='tmp.txt',access='stream',status='replace')
   write(fd) str
   close(fd)

   open(newunit=fd,file='tmp.txt',access='stream',status='old')
   do
      read(fd,end=10) c
      if (ichar(c) == 10) then
         inquire(unit=fd,pos=i)  ! Find the file position
         write(fd,pos=i-1) ' '   ! Backup 1 position and write
      end if
   end do
10   close(fd)

end program foo



Thanks.  Worked great. Have no idea why I was having a problem getting the write to fd to take with my code, but it works now.

You're welcomed!  But, heed @PierU.  It soemtimes easier for us to help by seeing the actual code you've written.
